# How to Create Multiple Sync Adapters in Android

Tags: android, synchronization

Ive started on android sync adapters and successfully created a working sync adapter.
bt my query is, how can o make multiple sync adapters, like i have two tables and i want two different Sync adapaters for each table.

Answer (score 0):

It may be late reply, but it can help others.

Create multiple sync adapters with different content providers

```
<service android:exported="true" android:name="com.sync.Sync1AdapterService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/sync_adapter1" />
</service>
<service android:exported="true" android:name="com.example.Sync2AdapterService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/sync_adapter2" />
</service>
```

sync_adapter1

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="sync1"
    android:accountType="com.sync.example"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="true" />
```

sync_adapter2

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="sync2"
    android:accountType="com.sync.example"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="true" />
```